How to open wsl in vscode?
I want to open wsl in vscode to run ubuntu scripts. I have input 'code .' in wsl, it can successfully open the vscode interface but unable to connect it and get the error like this:
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.062] Extension version: 0.88.5
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.063] L10N bundle: file:///c%3A/Users/Gaoqd/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.88.5/l10n/bundle.l10n.zh-cn.json
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.097] authorityHierarchy: wsl+Ubuntu-20.04
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.097] WSL extension activating for a local WSL instance
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.115] Resolving wsl+Ubuntu-20.04, resolveAttempt: 1
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.116] NodeExecServer run: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe --status
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.307] WSL feature installed: true (wsl --status)
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.307] NodeExecServer run: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe --list --verbose
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.475] 1 distros found
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.476] Starting VS Code Server inside WSL (wsl2)
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.476] Windows build: 22631. Multi distro support: available. WSL path support: enabled
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.476] Scriptless setup: false
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.739] NodeExecServer run: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e sh -c [ -f '/tmp/vscode-distro-env.CyHss1' ] && cat '/tmp/vscode-distro-env.CyHss1' || echo ''
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.829] WSL daemon log file:
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.830] Probing if server is already installed: if [ -d ~/.vscode-server/bin/f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813 ]; then printf 'install-found '; fi; if [ -f /etc/alpine-release ]; then printf 'alpine-'; fi; if [ -s ~/.vscode-server/bin/legacy-mode ]; then printf 'legacy-'; fi; uname -m;
[2024-12-05 13:41:52.830] NodeExecServer run: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e sh -c if [ -d ~/.vscode-server/bin/f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813 ]; then printf 'install-found '; fi; if [ -f /etc/alpine-release ]; then printf 'alpine-'; fi; if [ -s ~/.vscode-server/bin/legacy-mode ]; then printf 'legacy-'; fi; uname -m;
[2024-12-05 13:41:53.372] Using shell environment from invoking shell: /tmp/vscode-distro-env.CyHss1, 77 variables.
[2024-12-05 13:41:53.447] Probing result: install-found x86_64
[2024-12-05 13:41:53.448] Server install found in WSL
[2024-12-05 13:41:53.448] NodeExecServer run: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04 sh -c '"$VSCODE_WSL_EXT_LOCATION/scripts/wslServer.sh" f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813 stable code-server .vscode-server --host=127.0.0.1 --port=0 --connection-token=863315541-3702812910-3928786281-2457301640 --use-host-proxy --without-browser-env-var --disable-websocket-compression --accept-server-license-terms --telemetry-level=all'
[2024-12-05 13:41:53.762] wsl: �hKm0R localhost �NtM�n
�FO*g\��P0R WSL0NAT !j_
N/ec localhost �Nt0                                                          N�v WSL
[2024-12-05 13:41:53.762]
It stop in 'Installing WSL Components' and get this error. If I ignore this error, i can't open the files. I have install the wsl component in vscode. So, does there other component need to be installed or any other solutions to fix it?

Need more information wsl is enabled in vscode. what is exactly that you are trying to do ?

Well, i want to run ubuntu scripts in vscode. But i failed to open vscode and stopped in 'installing wsl components'. The logs have been added. Maybe i missed some steps?

What do you mean with "this error"? Nothing in the output says "error" or even "warning". Are you leaving the last line out? Only has the date+time there. Have you searched the error text yet? Like vscode stuck installing wsl components

I have checked the log file and found the last line indeed only has data and time. I can't add the snapshot here, the error is a window will pop up showing that VS code Server for WSL failed to start.

This is odd, it worked for me "out-off-the-box".  The fonts of the message might be a lead.  did you use an all english solution in your names, ?
